# Use custom Soap Header in cics web service(requester)

Tags: cobol, webservice-client, zos, cics

Can I add custom soap header in cics requester?
I have a soap web service A1 which running on mainframe(cics project), and it use a custom soap header like this:

```
<Header>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>
</Header>
```

Now I want to invoke this web service from a cobol program(requester) using **exec cics invoke web service** command.
How can I add this custom header to request?
Thanks in advance for any idea ))

Comment: You should have a look at [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=handlers-header-processing-programs), describing how to add a header processing program to your requester pipeline. 
If you haven't fiddled with handlers earlier, this might be a tough read though...
I have done it in the past, but it has been a while ago... Might you need more information, please let me know :)